# Pop rows of a numpy array with delete()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

With the following code, I iterate over an array in reverse order and print and pop the last item. In the end I expect to see an empty array, but it is not empty.

```
a = array([5,1,2,4,9,2]).reshape(-1, 1)
for j in a[::-1]:
    print(j.item())
    np.delete(a, len(a)-1, 0)
print("a=", a)
```

Output is

```
2
9
4
2
1
5
a= [[5]
 [1]
 [2]
 [4]
 [9]
 [2]]
```

How can I fix that? With the syntax of `delete(array, pos, axis)`, I expect to delete the rows from last to start.

Comment: why are you using an array as though it were a list?  Why not just work with a list?

Comment: @hpaulj: This is a snippet. In the actual code, I want to use KernelDensity and based on examples, I chose np array with that reshape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) does **not** work in place:

```
>>> np.delete(a, len(a)-1, 0)
array([[5],
       [1],
       [2],
       [4],
       [9]])
```

I am not sure why you would want to iterate over an array this way but you would need:

```
a = np.array([5,1,2,4,9,2]).reshape(-1, 1)
for j in a[::-1]:
    print(j.item())
    a = np.delete(a, len(a)-1, 0)  ## assign back to a
print("a=", a)
```

output:

```
2
9
4
2
1
5
a= []
```

Comment: OK. So isn't there to accomplish that with a better time complexity? because in that way, every time the array is copied.

Comment: @mahmood you should probably explain what is your ultimate goal. You could maybe slice the array using the position?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [108]: a = np.array([5,1,2,4,9,2]).reshape(-1, 1)
In [109]: a1 = a.copy()
```

This trims down `a1` without making a copy - it is just a successive slice/view:

```
In [111]: for j in a1[::-1]:
     ...:     print(j)
     ...:     a1 = a1[:-1]
     ...: 
[2]
[9]
[4]
[2]
[1]
[5]
In [112]: a1
Out[112]: array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=int64)
```

The `base` is still the array created in [109]

```
In [115]: a1.base
Out[115]: 
array([[5],
       [1],
       [2],
       [4],
       [9],
       [2]])
```